# Set up a user with specific properties

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, user-accounts

I need to set up a User on Windows XP Professional that has:

- no possibility to power off or reboot (BUT it should be possible for an admin to reboot/log off somehow)
- no taskbar
- no access to any hard disk/programs/files

all he should have is a few icons on the desktop, and those icons should be clickable to start those programs. aside from that there should be NOTHING he can do.

this user should auto log in on boot.

is this possible? if so how?

Comment: Does the User have physical access to the machine? If so, the 1st point is impossible (because you only need to press the power on button). If you want him to access some programs then you will need to allow *some* access to the hard disk. The 2nd is... possible, using Group Policies, as described below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with Windows XP Professional (but not with the Home edition.) You would accomplish this with the Microsoft Management Console (MMC) which you can open by typing mmc in the Run dialog box. You would then need to open the Group Policy Editor snap-in. [This site](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7553/remove-shutdown-and-restart-buttons-in-windows-7/) has a few pictures of how to disable the shutdown command by using this method. It would also be used for hiding the task bar.

You can block access to directory listings with this tool as well, but remember that the user will still be able to access files which list him as "read" in their file permissions. To restrict access to these files, place him or her into a user group that does not have these permissions.

The [Local Group Policy Editor Snap-In](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725970.aspx) for the Microsoft Management Console, in general, can be used to make all sorts of Windows customizations, especially where an administrator needs to restrict access to certain parts of the Explorer interface.

Comment: thanks! but i found that if i do your example of the shutdown comand it is doen for all users, including the admin.. why is that?

Comment: If you want to apply this setting to only certain users, you will need to make sure they are a part of a group that can share the restriction. I'm not sure if there's a way to restrict certain users, as the Group Policy Editor only works on groups. To make changes to groups, check out [this page](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/101869-local-group-policies-apply-all-users-except-administrators.html).